# Help calculating a multivariable limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^4+y^2}$$

I need to show that it doesn't equal 0.

Since the power of $x$ is 3 and 4 down it seems like that part could go to $0$ but the power of $y$ is 3 and 2 down so that seems like it's going to $\infty$.

I wonder if that even makes sense.

So how can I solve this limit, with substitution or changing it into a polar representation?

Comment: Hint: Consider two sequences converge to $(0, 0)$: $(x_n, y_n)=(0, \frac{1}{n})$ and $(x_n', y_n')=(\frac{1}{n}, 0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit just **doesn't exist** ('is undefined'), for exactly the reasons you describe. Therefore, it is not equal to zero.

Comment: So i actually solved without knowing, i really need practice

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^4+y^2}$. Then

$|f(x,x^2)| \to \infty$ for $x \to 0$.

Hence $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^4+y^2}$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

*Graphically* **f** looks like this : [image: pic1]
You can see that the value limit $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ **depends** on the path we take.

$\\  
\\  $

If we take the path $\lim_{(x,0) \rightarrow (0_{+},0)} f$, **graphically** it is this path :  [image: 1st path]

We find $+ \infty$. And if we plug this limit in **f** we find : $\lim_{(x,0) \rightarrow (0_{+},0)} \frac{x^3}{x^4} = \lim_{(x,0) \rightarrow (0_{+},0)} \frac{1}{x} = +\infty$

$\\ $

And the other limit we will consider is $\lim_{(x,0) \rightarrow (0_{-},0)} f$, **graphically** it is this path : [image: 2nd path]

We find $- \infty$. And if we plug this limit in **f** we find : $\lim_{(x,0) \rightarrow (0_{-},0)} \frac{x^3}{x^4} = \lim_{(x,0) \rightarrow (0_{-},0)} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty$

**To conclude**, we have : $$\lim_{(x,0) \rightarrow (0_{-},0)} f \neq \lim_{(x,0) \rightarrow (0_{+},0)} f$$

So the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f$ doesn't exist !